Why do questions not get locked after a period of inactivity?
At least in exchanges where "necro-posting" is banned, questions do not get locked after a period of inactivity, and therefore can still have answers and comments added. If moderation actions are taken specially on "necro" posts, then why can they be made?

Are there SE sites that ban posting late answers to old questions?

I'm not aware of any Stack Exchange sites where necro-posting is banned. It is always perfectly acceptable to answers questions years after they were posted, as long as you're not merely repeating what's stated in the existing answers. Can you provide examples of occasions where where you believe necro-posts have been deleted by moderators, for no reason other than because they were necro-posts?

Necro-posting is just not banned on Stack Exchange. If a question should be locked because it is no longer possible to receive applicable answers or is out of date, it probably should have been closed in the first place, as part of regular curation. If new answers are being deleted just because they're new, that's poor curation, but I would be extremely doubtful that "they were posted years later" is the key reason for deletion, let alone a reason at all.

Necromancy: acceptable. Posting an answer years later that adds no new information: certainly frowned upon. The content of a late answer is critical to whether it’s acceptable or not. There’s even a “late answers” review queue to help curators go through those late answers to check whether they’re adding any new or valuable information

Personally, I find making rules against 'necroposting' silly. If someone has a solution a decade later, let them share.

We're trying to find answers for the OP and the next person with the problem. In some cases people find answers years later, or find better answers for existing posts
There's even two badges - revival and necromancer that encourage quality late answers.
The only reason to close (not lock) an old question is if there's a newer better question with answers.
Allowing 'post necromancy' also fits our longer term goal of building a knowledge base for the long run.
